# Is it possible to make a fan chart with dygraphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I'm wanting to combine multiple lower/value/upper style series in one graph with shaded bars. Is it possible to create?

For example, for xts object "new_df" below:

```
df <- data.frame("value" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "upper1" = c(1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 4.6, 5.9), "lower1" = c(0.5, 1.8, 2.6, 3.7, 4.9), "upper2" = c(1.2, 2.1, 3.5, 4.8, 5.9), "lower2" = c(0.3, 1.4, 2.7, 3.5, 4.8))
dates <- c("2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01")
time <- as.Date(dates)
new_df <- as.xts(df, order.by = time)
```

This is new_df:

[image]

This is example of plot that I want to get, but I want to get multiple in one graph
[image]

Comment: Please add example of the plot you want.

Comment: Why for some cases `upper1 > upper2` and for other ones it's `upper2 > upper1` (the same is with `lower`).

Comment: I already added example, See "example of plot that I want"

Comment: Check comment about your data

Comment: There is obviously no link between your data and your graph ..

Comment: I want to get graph of value with intervals (lower1 - upper1) and (lower2: upper2)

Comment: And no link between your graph and your question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
dygraph(new_df, main = "testing") %>%
  dySeries(c("lower1", "value", "upper1"), label = "num1") %>% 
  dySeries(c("lower2", "value", "upper2"), label = "num2")
```

Comment: I'm really glad that everything worked out. Thank you so much! @MLavoie

Comment: @Cuong.S if the answer works for you, can you accept it?